# react-webcam - disable buttons until stream starts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-ref

I am using the [react-webcam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam) to capture images and videos in my react app. I have implemented the **Screenshot (via Ref)** example:

```
const videoConstraints = {
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
  facingMode: "user"
};

const WebcamCapture = () => {
  const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
  const capture = React.useCallback(
    () => {
      const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
    },
    [webcamRef]
  );
  return (
    <>
      <Webcam
        audio={false}
        height={720}
        ref={webcamRef}
        screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
        width={1280}
        videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
      />
      <button onClick={capture}>Capture photo</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Works nicely, however it seems to take a few seconds for the stream to start and video to start showing. I want to be able to disable the button whilst this is happening. I have found there is a flag in the `webcamRef` that states if it is loading:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (webcamRef.current) {
      const camStarted = webcamRef.current.state.hasUserMedia;
      debugger;
    }
  }, [webcamRef]);
```

In the above `useEffect`, whilst the video is initialising, the `hasUserMedia` is false, once it has loaded it changes to true. This sounds like exactly what I need however as it is in a `useRef`, it doesn't hit the `useEffect` when it changes.

Is there any kind of neat trick I can implement to be able to identify when this value in the `useRef` is changed, or anything else that might help me get the functionality I am after?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable the button until the camera has started streaming, you can use a check that can be triggered using the onUserMedia prop of Webcam.

```
const videoConstraints = {
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
  facingMode: "user"
};

const WebcamCapture = () => {
  const [loadingCam, setLoadingCam] = useState(true);
 
  const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
  const capture = React.useCallback(
    () => {
      const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
    },
    [webcamRef]
  );

  const handleUserMedia = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    // timer is optional if the loading is taking some time.
      setLoadingCam(false);
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Webcam
        audio={false}
        height={720}
        ref={webcamRef}
        screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
        width={1280}
        videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
        onUserMedia={handleUserMedia}
      />
      <button disable={loadingCam} onClick={capture}>Capture photo</button>
    </>
  );
};
```